# prefix for modules getting loaded using requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs

My application has different modules which ask for a files in following way :

```
var urlRepository = require('modules/common/urlrepository/urlrepository');
```

also some modules are required using following way :

```
require(['modules/common/urlrepository/urlrepository'],function(urlrepository){
    });
```

Now, suppose I've a same structure in 2 folders like :

```
    folder1
    |
    modules
    |
    common

    folder2
    |
    modules
    |
    common
```

Is there any way so that I can define a global variable like `currentFolder ="folder2"`
& depending on the variable it will load the respective modules.

I don't want to change the existing code inside each file.
I want something which will get appended before my require calls.

Comment: Do you have a script tag like this? <script data-main="scripts/main.js" src="scripts/require.js"></script>

Comment: yes. In a similar manner.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming folder1 and folder2 are children of the baseUrl directory:

To use folder1, put this in your main js file:

```
require.config({paths: {"modules": "folder1/modules"}})
```

To use folder2, put this in your main js file:

```
require.config({paths: {"modules": "folder2/modules"}})
```

Comment: paths config can be used as a shortcut for files. If that file is requiring some other file using relative path then it doesn't work, cause in case of relative paths again baseURL gets appended not the resolved url.So can not use path config to achieve the mentioned task.

Answer (score 0):

Not recommended but this as I see this can be achieved by putting a proxy in front of require call.
You can define your own require function which makes call to actual require  from inside of it. You can put your changes to url to retrieve inside your own require.

Sample code can be given as follows.

```
var oldrequire = require;
require = function(){
    var prefix = global.mode;
    if(typeof arguments[0]==='string'){
        oldrequire(prefix+arguments[0]);
        return;
    }
    var arr = arguments[0];
    if(arr instanceof Array){
        for(var index in arr){
            arr[index] = prefix+arr[index];
        }
        oldrequire(arguments);
    }
}
```

You may also need to override define function since it uses a relative require to get the files.

Note : Saying again. this is not recommended since you are not sure of how a particular require call might behave.